# Is there a way to Imitate C# 6 Null-Conditional operator in C# 5

Tags: c#, .net, c#-5.0, c#-6.0

I have a situation where I need to assign some objects' properties inside an object initializer. Some of these objects can be null and I need to access their properties, the problem is that they are too many, and using a if/else thing is not good.

**Example**

```
visits = visitJoins.AsEnumerable().Select(joined => new VisitPDV()
{
    VisiteId = joined.Visite.VisiteId.ToString(),
    NomPointDeVente = joined.VisitePdvProduit.PointDeVente.NomPointDeVente,             
});
```

The `joined.VisitePdvProduit` can be null, and the problem is that there are like dozens of such assignments (I just took one to shorten the code)

The `C# 6` `Null-Conditional operator` is the perfect solution for this situation, the problem is that I'm on `C# 5` in this project, is there a way to imitate that ?

Comment: Create an extension method

Comment: How about `visitJoins.AsEnumerable().Where(vj => vj.VisitePdvProduit != null).Select(joined => new VisitPDV()`

Comment: @ClayVerValen as I said I have multiple assignments like that , I just shortened it to avoid long code here, doing your suggestion won't help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, you can use an extension method that receives an accessor delegate and only executes it if the item isn't `null`:

```
public static TResult ConditionalAccess<TItem, TResult>(this TItem item, Func<TItem, TResult> accessor) where TResult : Class
{
    if (item == null)
    {
        return null;
    }
    else
    {
        return accessor(item);
    }
}
```

You can use it for example like this:

```
NomPointDeVente = joined.VisitePdvProduit.ConditionalAccess(_ => _.PointDeVente.NomPointDeVente);
```

You can easily create versions of this method for operations that don't return a value (i.e. `bar.ConditionalAccess(_ => _.Foo())`) or return value types.

Comment: This would only work for the top-level property expansion.

Comment: Why does `TResult` have to be a class?  What if you're dealing with `Nullable<T>` which is a `struct`?

Comment: @i3arnon, you would have to call it on each level of property expansion.

Comment: @juharr You need to special-case returning value types because the delegate needs to compile with `TResult` but the return value needs to be `Nullable<TResult>`

Comment: @Amy sure.. but it works for every level. Just as you need to use `?.` for each conditional access.

Comment: @i3arnon Yeah there's the case where the function would return a struct and you need to wrap that in a `Nullable` but there's also the case were the function returns a `Nullable`.  Basically it's not this simple to reverse engineer the `?.` operator.

Comment: @juharr There's also the case where it doesn't return anything. If it was simple it wouldn't be a compiler feature. But it is possible...

Answer (score 1):

Like this. Ugly, but what had to be done.

```
 visits = visitJoins.AsEnumerable().Select(joined => new VisitPDV()
 {
     VisiteId = joined.Visite.VisiteId.ToString(),
     NomPointDeVente = (joined.VisitePdvProduit == null) ? null : joined.VisitePdvProduit.PointDeVente.NomPointDeVente,             
 });
```

Comment: Doesn't deserve a downvote, not sure why, true it's lil bit ugly as you said, but it does the job, and it's understandable, upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about the *semi-very surprised* operator *?.*, then no. There's no way to mimic the syntax.

What you can do, though, is to create an extension method (or a helper method, static one, preferably) or an instance method working with the properties.

Or, as someone suggested, just use the conditional statement (inline or explicit). But that's not what you're looking for, of course.

One more method (and it's **not at all** recommendable) is to surround the assignment with a *try-catch*. But that's **really baaad** solution and I only mention it for completeness' sake.

Comment: Nope. [This operator: `?.`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx).

Comment: "very surprised operator" ?  Is that a typo?

Comment: @NickWhaley Sorry, too fast on the key. Corrected the answer.

Comment: @Amy Yes, typo. I corrected to the right one. The answer is the same. I just typed in wrong (and called it semi-wrong, teehee).

Comment: I've also heard it called the Elvis operator.