# C# 5 extension method working as the C# 6 null conditional operator

Tags: c#

I have a piece of code similar to:

```
var colour = car.Wheels[0].Trim.Bolts[0].Colour.Substring(0, 3);
```

Unfortunately car, Wheels, Trim, Bolts, Colour can all be null; Wheels, Bolts and Colour can be empty as well.

Is there an Object extension method I can use that will do all the null/empty checks for me?

I'd prefer a solution that can easily be replaced with the ?. operator, once I upgrade to C# 6+.

Comment: No, there is no replacement for the [null conditional operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx)

Comment: You can't use C# 6.0 yet? Are you stuck on VS 2013 for some reason?

Comment: How to emulate C# 6 null-conditional in C# < 6 (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34483974/how-to-emulate-c-sharp-6-null-conditional-in-c-sharp-6)

Comment: `var colour = car != null ? car.Wheels != null && car.Wheels[0] != null ? car.Wheels[0].Trim != null  ? car.Wheels[0].Trim.Bolts != null && car.Wheels[0] != null ? car.Wheels[0].Trim.Bolts[0].Colour != null ? car.Wheels[0].Trim.Bolts[0].Colour.Substring(0, 3) : string.Empty;` o.O

Comment: @m.rogalski If I saw that in production code I'd refactor it into `if` statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this extension method?

```
public static T IfNotNull<R, T>(this R r, Func<R, T> selector)
{
    if (r != null)
    {
        return selector(r);
    }
    else
    {
        return default(T);
    }
}
```

Which will leave you with this nasty code:

```
var colour = car.Wheels.IfNotNull(w => w.FirstOrDefault())
                       .IfNotNull(w => w.Trim)
                       .IfNotNull(w => w.Substring(0, 3));
```

Personally I would still prefer simple `if` statements.

Comment: A bit strong to say the *only* option. You can throw together some generic extension methods that take lambdas and return null or the result of the lambda.

Comment: And how would you check those without `if`? Things get very hard without `if` :)

Comment: @Rawling I just thought about trying to code something like that, but OP's point is it "can easily be reaplaced with the ?. operator", which I think it can't.

Comment: @PatrickHofman `input == null ? null : selector(input)`?

Comment: @PatrickHofman, [extension method](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34027844/1997232) ?

Comment: @Sinatr Thanks for ruining my party ;) . Just wrote that myself...

Comment: You'd need to specify that `T` is a class and have another version for strcts that returns `Nullable<T>` in general.

Comment: Possible, yes. Still I hope no one with ever use that code. @juharr